# How to get the time when two capsules will collide

Tags: line, physics, collision

I'm working on a simple collision system focusing on having capsules collide. Using many resources, but primarily [this site](http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html#dist3D_Segment_to_Segment) I have been able to get two capsules to collide with each other. This method gives me the shortest distance between two line segments. I then check that against the combined radius of the two capsules to see if a collision occurs.

This is working, but there are two issues with this solution:

1. If objects are moving very fast, to the point where they will move through each other, the radius check will fail, and the objects will pass through each other.
2. When a collision does occur, I have no way that I know of to make the objects flush to actually be touching (for example, when a character lands on the ground).

I have another function that I found [here](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131790/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?print=1) using spheres, that will return the time at which the two spheres will collide. When using this function, and I detected a collision (time < 1) I can just multiply the object's velocity for that frame by the time and make the objects flush. I'm really looking for a way to modify the segment collision function from that site to give me the same information with the segment to segment collision.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is helpful...

usually, problem #1 has no direct solution and will haunt you forever. Time integration step must be smaller enough to prevent it from happening with the velocities you use. (this is especially true if somehow you can only calculate positive distances=|x2-x1|...)

I'm not really getting the difference between capsules and spheres, but
aren't you calculating the distance, for each dimension before and after dt:

```
   dx = obj1.x - obj2.x;
   dy = obj1.y - obj2.y;
   dz = obj1.z - obj2.y;  
   dxlater = obj1.x + obj1.vx*dt - (obj2.x + obj2.vx*dt);
   dylater = obj1.x + obj1.vy*dt - (obj2.y + obj2.vy*dt);
   dzlater = obj1.x + obj1.vz*dt - (obj2.z + obj2.vz*dt);
```

if dx and dxlater have different sign, the object collided, ie if:

```
   if (dx*dxlater < 0) // collision occured
```

if you want to know when the collision occured, solve distance=RAD_SUM for t: (for all dimensions)

```
   obj1.x + obj1.vx*tc - (obj2.x + obj2.vx*tc) = RAD_SUM
```

should be:

```
   tc = (RAD_SUM + obj2.x - obj1.x)/(obj1.vx - obj2.vx)
```

calculate positions to that point as normal, then new speeds, then apply newspeeds till the end of that `dt`

Comment: This sounds like it will work, but I don't have the points of the closest line (obj1 and obj2 in your example). I only have the distance. The algorithm provided in the first link uses vector math to acquire the distance, without a way to get the two end points of that line. If I could get the end points of the line that is the distance between the two lines, I could try your solution.

Comment: "the distance between the two lines" is obj2.x-obj1.x, right?